# Binding an Enum to LINQ and SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, forms

I'm trying to bind the following enum

```
public enum CertificateTypes : byte
{
    None = 0,
    Original = 1,
    AuthenticatedCopy = 2,
    Numbered = 3
}
```

to a `tinyint` column on the database. However, when creating the SelectListItems and calling, for instance, `Person.CertificateTypes.Original.ToString() I get this:`

```
<option value="Original">Original</option>
```

which is not bindable to a byte? column. How should I do this? Should I explicitly set the value to "1" on the `Value` property of the SelectListItem? Or is there a way to make this work "automagically"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want automagically you can use

```
var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CertificateTypes)).Cast<CertificateTypes>().Select(e => (byte)e);
var selectList = new SelectList(enumValues);
```

Problem here is you're only going to get the bytes, so you would probably need to select a new type something like...

```
var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CertificateTypes)).Cast<CertificateTypes>()
                                                         .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<byte, string>((byte)e, e.ToString()));
var selectList = new SelectList(enumValues, "Key", "Value");
```

That would just take possible values from the enum and translate it into an IEnumerable of CertificateTypes then taking each value and translating it into a new KeyValuePair.

One thing to note, it's usually a good idea to only make your enums pluralized if you have a [Flags] attribute on them.  Otherwise I would name it singular.

Gotta love LINQ!

Comment: +1:  Was looking for this solution for shorts instead of bytes for the Keys.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the following translates to a `SelectListItems` in ASP.NET/MVC, though, as I have no experience, but maybe this can be of use.

---

Of course you have to specifically cast the enum to it's underlying type like `(byte)Person.CertificateTypes.Original` to get it to talk to the database nicely.

In WinForms, I use an `IList` of `KeyValuePair<byte,string>` to bind to a `ComboBox`, using something like the following:

```
foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CertificateTypes))
    MyBindingIList.Add(new KeyValuePair<byte,string>((byte)value, value.ToString()));
```

I then bind the `ComboBox` and set it's `DisplayMember` to `"Value"` and `ValueMember` to `"Key"`. (You can switch the `Key` and `Value` in the `KeyValuePair` to whatever makes sense for you. For me, the key comes out of the database, so it makes sense to be the numeric type.)

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that calling `ToString()` on an enum returns xml... can you clarify what *is* happening? You probably want to either cast the enum to an byte/int (and work in terms of numbers much of the time), or use `Enum.Parse` at some point - but it is hard to say without understanding how you have got it hooked together...